# Проблемы с Maven, не собирает конкретный проект

Tags: java, maven, selenium

[image: Ошибка Maven]

Не собирается проект. Maven установлен по инструкции, созданы переменные и указаны адреса в переменных средах, другие проекты собирает, а вот проект с использованием Selenium не хочет. Зависимости нужные\не нужные подключены, но элементарно создать WebDriver с использованием ChromeDriver невозможно.

Comment: Привет, прикрепи, пожалуйста, содержимое pom.xml и полное сообщение об ошибке.

Answer (score 0):

Найди папку m2 у себя и почисти её содержимое, вернись в проект и заново перекачай зависимости, возможно поможет =)